How to achieve drag item from one category to another category by using two different recyclerview
How to implement dragging one item from category related stickers to another category when having 2 different recyclerView and different viewHolder. refer below animation

I tried to add dragListerner but when we drag particular sticker to another recyclerview item and drop then its again go back to original position.
In Adapter :
gifClickAction?.let { gif ->
                sivGifImage.setOnLongClickListener {
                    gif(gifs, adapterPosition)
                    true
                }
            }

In Fragment :
gifAdapter.gifActionClick { gif, _ ->
                        val dragListener = View.OnDragListener { v, event ->
                            when (event.action){
                                DragEvent.ACTION_DROP ->{
                                    //val targetCategory = v.tag as Gifs
                                    gifAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    true
                                }
                                else -> true
                            }
                        }

                        gifs.forEach {
                            val stickerView = binding.rvFavourites.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(it.id)?.itemView
                            stickerView?.tag = it
                            stickerView?.setOnDragListener(dragListener)
                        }

                        val item = ClipData.Item(gif.title)
                        val dragData = ClipData(gif.title, arrayOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN), item)
                        val shadow = View.DragShadowBuilder(binding.rvFavourites.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(gif.id)?.itemView)
                        binding.rvFavourites.startDragAndDrop(dragData, shadow, null, 0)
                    }
            }

with above code I am able to achieve only drag to another recyclerview,


You need to show us the code you have so far and tell us specifically what problem you are facing. Please make sure the code you share is a [mre], make it as short as possible to demonstrate the problem.

@Leviathan edited details, pls refer code and gif
